# TLC5946 no output when BLANK is LOW

Tags: serial, led-driver

I'm testing the [TLC5946](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc5946.pdf?ts=1654011639195) LED driver and I'm trying to bitbang into it's registers with this bit of code:

```
void bitbang(bool high, uint8_t bits) {
  digitalWrite(LED_DAT, high ? HIGH : LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  
  for(uint16_t i = 0; i < bits; i++) {
    digitalWrite(LED_SCK, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(5);
    digitalWrite(LED_SCK, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(5);
  }
}

void prep_DC() {
  digitalWrite(LED_MODE, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  
  bitbang(HIGH, 96);

  digitalWrite(LED_LATCH, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  digitalWrite(LED_LATCH, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  digitalWrite(LED_MODE, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
}

void prep_GS() {
  digitalWrite(LED_MODE, HIGH);  

  bitbang(HIGH, 192);

  digitalWrite(LED_LATCH, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  digitalWrite(LED_LATCH, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_SCK, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_DAT, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_LATCH, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_BLANK, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_MODE, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(LED_BLANK, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(LED_LATCH, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED_SCK, LOW);

  prep_DC();
  prep_GS();

  digitalWrite(LED_BLANK, LOW);
}

void loop() {
}
```

That seems to work fine, however the TLC5946 doesn't light the LEDs up - They only very briefly blink. With some experimentation, I found out that cycling of the LED_BLANK pin is what makes the
LEDs blink.

So when I add

```
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BLANK, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  digitalWrite(LED_BLANK, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
}
```

the LEDs light up, with the correct GS PWM, it seems. I'm pretty sure the GSCLK is not the problem, since when I disconnect it, the LEDs don't even blink. Simmilary, the actual data latched into the IC seems right, correct LEDs turned on/off when I tried bitbanging something other than all 1s.

Is clocking the BLANK pin correct way to use this IC? If so, when should it be clocked, and where is it described in the datasheet? (I couldn't find that information) If not, what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: The `bitbang` function ignores its second parameter. You have two functions called `prep_GS`. If you want to do PWM, you need GSCLK.

Comment: Fixed mistakes in code. GSCLK is clocked from outside source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datasheet says:

> The counter is reset to zero when the BLANK signal is set high.
> […]
> When the counter becomes FFFh, the counter stops and output does not turn on until the next grayscale cycle.

So BLANK must be pulsed high after every 4096 GSCLK cycles (or less then that if you do not need 12-bit PWM resolution).

If you do not need PWM at all, then you can pulse BLANK high, send a rising edge on GSCLK, and then do not send any more GSCLK cycles.